# VisualCrumbs - StackExchange Visual Changes

Tags: script, design

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

I created this script because I wanted to customize my personal use of Stack Overflow (And such Stack Exchange sites) to be more visually appealing to me and give me a little bit of functionality that I believe is lacking.

Currently, this script will make better use of the screen space, making the content much larger and minimizing the space taken by the sidebars.

It also puts everything in the right sidebar in a nice little box.

Note: This works best with the responsive themes.

#### Download

https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/Userscripts

Greasyfork: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/369480-visualcrumbs-stack-visuals

#### Platform

Created with Tampermonkey

### Contact

GrumpyCrouton - [GitHub](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton)

### Code

Built using jQuery in Tampermonkey.

### Issues

If there are any issues, please post a comment below and I will attempt to fix it and update my repo.

Comment: If you'd rename the file to something with an `.user.js` ending, you could provide a direct install link (With the Raw URL)

Comment: @filnor do you mean on github?

Comment: Yes, I mean on GitHub.